# C# projects in a solution now displaying as F#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, projects-and-solutions

Using the dotnet cli interface in a VS Code Terminal.  I have created  a blank solution file, a blank project file and added the project to the new solution. Now when I open the folder it opens a F# solution explorer? Is this default behavior?

steps:

1. dotnet new sln
2. dotnet new console -lang c#
3. dotnet sln test.sln add test.csproj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed `Ionide` plugin it will always try to open solution explorer by default. You can disable it in settings: press `ctrl + ,` and add this switch

```json
{
    "FSharp.showExplorerOnStartup": false,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I searched for language specifiers with no luck.